# React Native - Not getting response of a API(response size is large around 600KB) when application running on mobile

Tags: android, react-native

I have a API which is called in my react native application.
This API is a has request method as GET. Also gzip(compression) is enabled on the server on which this API is hosted. The response size of this API around 678 KB and after gzip it is 239 KB.

When my react native application is running in debug mode then I am getting the complete and proper response from the API.
But when the application is installed on the actual device then I am not getting the response and its giving size as 0.

Following is the code for the API call -

```
async function getAppPropertiesFromApi() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch(
      'https://myserver.com/api/getProperties',{method: "GET"}
    );
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    return responseJson.appProps;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Is there any limitation on the response size when the application is running on the device ?

Note - I am getting proper response for the other API's that i am calling from my react native application. I am using fetch for the API communication.

Please provide me some pointers in this area and let me know if there is some change that i need to do to get the proper response. Thanks!

Comment: Please add your code in the question.

Comment: @Codesingh I have added my code in the question

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this problem and it's not related to any size constraints.

The mentioned API was expecting a Accept-Language header in the coming request. So when the application was running in debug mode on the rnd, the request were sent through the chrome browser and the browser by default attaches the Accept-Language header in the request. But when it was not running in the debug mode at that no Accept-Language header was sent in the header of the request, hence the issue was coming as I was not getting any data.

For fixing this I have added Accept-Language header in the request that are going through the mobile application.